# How can I use a batch shortcut to open multiple Windows Explorer folders, and a Notepad file?

Tags: windows-7, batch, shortcuts

I've recently built a computer with an SSD in it (my first) and am in the process of moving a select few of my Steam games to the SSD and symbolically linking them to where they're supposed to be on the main (mechanical) hard drive so that Steam doesn't throw a fit and I get maximum performance. To this end, I'm finding myself repeatedly navigating to both target folders to move the relevant files and opening a specific Notepad file to enter the relevant paths into a template I've got set up that I paste into the Windows command prompt to create the symlink. This is annoying.

I've read up a little bit on batch shortcuts, and have a basic understanding on how to use one to open programs and files. However, I'm finding a lot of confusing suggestions on how to use batch shortcuts to open specific folders in Windows Explorer, and none of them deal with opening multiple folders at once. Any assistance on writing the shortcut would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why don't you just create a list of path names, and the symlink locations, and then use a for loop in powershell to create all of the symlinks?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Start.exe` is your friend. :)

> Starts a separate window to run a specified program or command.

Try something like this in a batch file:

```
@echo off
start explorer c:\
start explorer c:\Windows
start explorer "g:\Path With Spaces"
start notepad.exe g:\filename.txt
```

Comment: @Moab `Start` has a `MIN` switch to help with that. :)  I.E.: `start /MIN explorer c:\ `

Comment: @Moab I'm not sure what you're asking me...?